# inception v3 mixed_10 layer predictions

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I have retrained inception v3 for my own classes and am trying to localise the detected classes in an input image.

Basically like this example which is looking for pedestrians in an image
http://silverpond.com.au/2016/10/24/pedestrian-detection-using-tensorflow-and-inception.html

So I have been able to get the 8x8x2048 output

```
with sess.as_default():
    softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('mixed_10/join:0')
    predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)[1].tostring()})

print len(predictions)

for r in predictions:
    print 'r',len(r)

    for c in r:
        print 'c',len(c)
        print c
```

Which gives me output like so:

```
1
r 8
c 8
[[ 1.47802579  0.45579425  0.32806152 ...,  0.          0.          0.315418  ]
 [ 1.36758661  0.51684511  1.30546498 ...,  0.          0.          0.42971259]
 [ 1.5746814   1.29075444  1.32023144 ...,  0.          0.23419005
   0.11281317]
 ...,
```

How do I convert these numbers to predictions for my classes?

Comment: the segmentation shown [here](http://warmspringwinds.github.io/tensorflow/tf-slim/2016/10/30/image-classification-and-segmentation-using-tensorflow-and-tf-slim/) is basically what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: The class output should be `tf.argmax(softmax_value)`.

Comment: thanks @drpng .   When I have the result from the argmax function it is a tensor... how do I get the value from it?  
                            smv=tf.nn.softmax(c)

                            cls=tf.argmax(smv,axis=0)
gives me: Tensor("ArgMax:0", shape=(), dtype=int64, device=/device:CPU:0)

Comment: Can you post more context? What was the error?